# Column Visibility based on previous multi-choice column in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a SP List with a column "Color" that is a choice type that allows multiple choices (Red, Green, Yellow). What I need is for a Number Red, Number Green, and Number Yellow column to be triggered as "Visible" if the user select any combination of Red Green or Yellow. EG

If user selects Red, the Number Red column becomes visible. If the user selects Red and Green, both the Number Red and the Number Green becomes visible in the data entry "form".

```
=if([$Color] == 'Red, 'true', 'false')
```

works when "Allow Multiple Choices" is false, but when I change it to "allowed", it stops working and the Number Red column is not visible in any scenario.

Google suggest that a conditional formula controlling column visibility based on a multi-choice does not work because the column value is no longer a simple string with multiple values, which makes sense, but Google also suggests that a Flow is the way to go here. I am not a programmer, just the poor junior analyst that got assigned making this form. Are there any examples of how to make this work with a flow at the ELI5 level?

Comment: This is not a PowerAutomate thing so no, “flow” is not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about choice column with multiple selections is not supported in SharePoint list form conditional formulas:

[image]

**Microsoft Documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

So, you will have to achieve your requirements using **Power Apps** (not Power Automate flow). You have to customize the list forms using Power Apps and show/hide number controls based on the choice column selection.

Check below links for more information:

1. [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)
2. [Hide /Show field depending on Multiple selections done in drop down menu](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Hide-Show-field-depending-on-Multiple-selections-done-in-drop/td-p/1934212)
3. [Hide/Show Field based on Combobox Multiple Selections](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Hide-Show-Field-based-on-Combobox-Multiple-Selections/td-p/2056298)